# Reading Excel Sheet Using C# Where the Table has Merged Cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, import-from-excel

I am trying to read an Excel sheet that has some merged cells using C#.  I read in another post that merged cells still existed from the code's point of view but they just had null values.  So I have tried skipping null values but I am still getting wonky results.  Here is the code I am using.  It is supposed to populate an HTML table with values from the spreadsheet:

```
private void Output_Excel_File()
{
    string inputFileLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/dashboard.xls";
    DataSet ds = Get_Spreadsheet_Data(inputFileLocation, "Dashboard Statistics");
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            int row = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int col = 0;
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    string cellValue = dr[dc].ToString();
                    cellValue = Regex.Replace(cellValue, "\n", "<br /");
                    if (cellValue == "X" || cellValue == null)
                    {
                        col++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    string index = "r" + row.ToString() + "c" + col.ToString();
                    Literal cellTarget = (Literal)form1.FindControl(index);
                    cellTarget.Text = cellValue;
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In particular my indexing is off and the line:

```
cellTarget.Text = cellValue;
```

always ends up throwing a null reference exception when the indexing becomes mismatched with the indexing in the HTML.

I've Googled and Googled but I'm stumped.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What does `Get_Spreadsheet_Data` do? Is this a library? Which one?

Comment: This code was given to me by someone with experience doing this sort of thing.  I just assumed that it worked.  When I debug I do see values from the spreadsheet in the variables but the indexing is off and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I remember, The upper left most cell of merged cells will carry the data. Every other cell reference in the merged group will be empty.

EDIT:
If you want to skip processing r0c1 (Because I assume it doesnt exist) if it is "X" or Null, then you would have to do something like this:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    string cellValue = dr[dc].ToString();
    cellValue = Regex.Replace(cellValue, "\n", "<br /"); 
    if (cellValue != "X" | cellValue != null)
    {
        string index = "r" + row.ToString() + "c" + col.ToString();
        Literal cellTarget = (Literal)form1.FindControl(index);
        cellTarget.Text = cellValue; 
    }

    col++;
}
```

Also I think cellValue will not ever be null, but it may be empty `""` so I like to use:

```
if (cellValue != "X" | cellValue.Length == 0)
```

EDIT2:

You may be a bit confused with the `NullRefference` exception that you are recieving. From what I see it not because the `cellValue` is null, it's from:

```
(Literal)form1.FindControl(index);
```

trying to find r0c1 which I assume doesn't exist and returns a null control(Literal). So when you go to use

```
cellTarget.Text = cellValue;
```

you get a NullReference error because the object itself `cellTarget` is null.

Comment: That's why I am skipping cells that return a null value.  But my indexing is still off.

Comment: It looks like the first time through on the loop your `index` is at R0C0 `string index = "r" + row.ToString() + "c" + col.ToString();` from `int col = 0;` and `int row = 0;`

Comment: The Literal control I am replacing in the HTML table has id="r0c0".  For some reason my index advances to r0c1 even though there is only one value in the first row of the table -- all of its cells being merged.

Comment: Hmm.  My table is 5x5 and the first row is 5 merged columns that just contains a title.  My understanding is that to traverse this row I still must iterate over the merged cells but they will have a null value.  Therefore skipping nulls should work, no?

Comment: Yes, but you are still hitting the line `Literal cellTarget = (Literal)form1.FindControl(index);` every time. I edited my answer to help.